# How to find transitively related (1 degree of separation) IDs in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

First time posting a question here, couldn't find the answer any other way.

I have a table for music bands

```
bands
id | name
```

and I have a musician table

```
musicians
id | first_name | last_name
```

I have created a third table, that links them via foreign keys

```
band_membership
band_id | musician_id
```

I have populated the `bands` table with a few bands and the `musicians` with a few musicians.

Then I linked musician `John Doe` (ID 1) to bands `Foo` (ID 1) and `Bar` (ID 2)

Then I linked musician `Jane Doe` (ID 2) to bands `Foo` (ID 1) and `Rab` (ID 3)

So these musicians share a band but also play in other bands separately.

The question is: How do I select all members of the band `Foo` and iterate through `Foo`s musicians and SELECT all band names which are related/associated with `Foo` through it's members? In this case I want the "input" band to be `Foo` and the SELECT result to be

```
1 | Bar
2 | Rab
```

Since these are the two bands which are directly (1 degree of separation) associated with `Foo` via the band member's other sideprojects/bands

I know I can select all the IDs of `Foo`s members (Jane and John) via the following query

```
SELECT m.id FROM musicians AS m
INNER JOIN band_membership AS bm ON m.id = bm.musician_id
INNER JOIN bands AS b ON bm.band_id = (SELECT id FROM bands WHERE name = 'Foo')
GROUP BY m.id
```

I also know I can find all the bands `John Doe` is a member of via the following query

```
SELECT b.name FROM bands AS b
INNER JOIN band_membership AS bm ON b.id = bm.band_id
INNER JOIN musicians as m ON bm.musician_id = 1
GROUP BY b.name
```

But for the life of me I cannot find a way to combine these.

The first query will return

```
1 | 1
2 | 2
```

which are John and Jane's IDs but how do I "plug" them into the second query, where the `1` is currently hardcoded.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use multiple joins:

```
select distinct b2.name
from bands b join
     band_membership bm
     on bm.band_id = b.id join
     band_membership bm2
     on bm2.musician_id = bm.musician_id join
     bands b2
     on bm2.band_id = b2.id
where b.name = 'Foo'
```